# Is it possible to filter which applications can use my iPhone's Personal Hotspot?

Tags: iphone, wifi, windows, tethering

Is it possible to filter which applications (in Windows) can use my iPhone's Personal Hotspot?

Comment: This might be better asked in a windows forum. The iPhone part is the personal hotspot software isn't configurable unless you jailbreak the phone and modify that code. Perhaps edit the question to ask this specifically if that is your intent.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. Even by jailbreaking would not enable this, or more exactly not in a practical way.

Answer (score 1):

Technically yes you can but it depends on what firewall you use.

Since the connection to the Hotspot will be a distinct Network Connection (interface), if your firewall will allow you limit apps based on process name and interface, then this will in fact achieve your goal.